# How to set the value of a text_field in html to 0 if left empty

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Suppose there is a text field, on loading the page the text box should show 0 in the box by default and if the value is not changed then the database should store 0 on submit action.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Maintenance %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :Maintenance %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

`<%= f.text_field :Maintenance , :value => 0 %>`

If you're using something like `simple_form` then you may need to wrap it like

`<%= f.text_field :Maintenance , :input_html => {:value => 0} %>`